# Loop items (list) of a variable, each item is also a variable with items (list)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

My code is something like this:

```
var allcategories = ["category1", "category2", "category3"];
var category1 = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
var category2 = ["item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8"];
var category3 = ["item9", "item10"];

for (let currentcategory of allcategories) {
    for (let categoryitem of currentcategory) {
        console.log (currentcategory, categoryitem);
    };
};
```

Each item listed in the "allcategories" variable is also a variable with saved items.
My goal is to get the value of the variables "category1, category2 category3 ..." but this only returns the first letter of the variable ("C").
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The string constants of allcategories are not the same as the array objects in the 3 lines below.

Answer (score 2):

You could also define your variables like this:

```
var category1 = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
var category2 = ["item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8"];
var category3 = ["item9", "item10"];

var allcategories = [category1, category2, category3];
```

Here you define 3 arrays and then define a "holding" array containing them.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be to have the variable names as property keys in an object instead:

```js
const allcategories = ["category1", "category2", "category3"];

const categoryObj = {
  category1: ["item1", "item2", "item3"],
  category2: ["item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8"],
  category3: ["item9", "item10"]
}

for (let currentcategory of allcategories) {
  for (let categoryitem of categoryObj[currentcategory]) {
    console.log(currentcategory, categoryitem);
  };
};
```